# Get date of first/last appearance of a series

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The title of this question is not clear but I do not know how to formulate it...
I have a dataframe that explain, at each minute, if there was queue at a skilift

the dataframe contain 2 cols:
- Minutes = minute we are looking at
- Queue = 1 if there was a queue at this minute, 0 otherwise

ex:

```python
from 08h00 to 10h00 each line get a 0 into "Queue"
from 10h01 to 10h45 each line get a 1 into "Queue"
from 10h46 to 14h00 each line get a 0 into "Queue"
from 14h01 to 14h45 each line get a 1 into "Queue"
from 10h45 to 17h30 each line get a 0 into "Queue"
```

I want to create a new dataframe with 2 columns

```python
----------------------
Start      |    End
----------------------
10h01      |   10h45
14h01      |   14h45
```

I manage to get a dataframe like this:

```python
----------------------
Start      |    End
----------------------
10h01      |   None
None       |   10h45
14h01      |   None
None       |   14h45
```

Using:

```python
df2=df.withColumn('start', F.when((F.col("Prev_Queue") == 0) & (F.col("Queue") == 1), F.col('NextMin')).otherwise(None))

df2=df2.withColumn('end', F.when((F.col("Next_Queue") == 0) & (F.col("Queue") == 1), F.col('NextMin')).otherwise(None))
```

Where "Prev_Queue" is the value of Queue at the previous minute and "Next_Queue" is the value of Queue at the next minute.

Any idea on how to get the dataframe I want (from the dataframe that I manage to get or with an easier way)?
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the help from a co-worker ;-)

For information I had one more column, "skilift", containing the name of the skilift I was interested with

Here is the solution:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('Skilift').orderBy('Minute')
df = df.withColumn("rnk", F.when(F.lag('Queue').over(w) != F.col('Queue'), 1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn('rnk2', F.sum('rnk').over(w))

df.where("queue = 1").groupBy('skilift','rnk2').agg(F.min('Minute'), F.max('Minute')).drop('rnk2').drop('rnk').show(truncate=False)
```